# How to get value of key when using jsonschema2pojo custom annotator on a input type of JSON

Tags: java, json, jsonschema2pojo

I am creating the POJOs using jsonschema2pojo on inputtype of JSON ( not Json schema ).  I need to add the APIModelProperty annotation to each primitive field and I would like to use the value as value for "example" parameter.

```
@ApiModelProperty(example="2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z")
```

I do not want to manually add this annotation to each field afterr the schema is generated.  So, I am trying to write a custom annotator that will add this annotation.  From the examples I have seen, I am trying to use the

```
@Override
public void propertyField(JFieldVar field, 
                      JDefinedClass clazz, 
                      String propertyName, 
                      JsonNode propertyNode ) {

    System.out.println("propertyName " + propertyName);
}
```

This gives me the key names from the JSON.  I have 2 questions

1. I want to add the @APIModelProperty annotation to each primitive
   field.  How do I identify that propertyName field is a primitive and
2. How do I get the value of propertyName?

Example - `"eventCreatedTime": "2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z"`

Thank you

Comment: @joelittlejohn - Any pointers on this one as well?  I tried to join the google group to ask the question, but it doesn't allow me to join with email id that is not a gmail id

Comment: Is is not possible  to get  the value of the key from the json document in the custom annotator that could be used in the @APIModelProperty for "example" parameter for value?

Comment: Does anybody have any pointers.  How can I achieve this @joelittlejohn ?